# Examples of "Strict Inheritance"

Tags: oop, programming-languages

I was reading about "Strict Inheritance" ([link](https://jyx.jyu.fi/bitstream/handle/123456789/27203/9789513943523.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)). It said:

> Inheritance is called strict if descendants do not delete or modify (override) any inherited features, non-strict otherwise.

Basically, if `A` and `B` are classes and `A` is the strict father of `B` then object of type `B` has the same behaviour as `A` with more features.

I was wondering if there is a language that supports that idea. As far as I know, Smalltalk and Java does not support it. Are there languages that support that idea? I would be glad to see an example. If there are no languages that support this idea, what could be the reason for it (why Java does not support it)?

I also read that C can imitate that idea due to its weak typing but I could not think of how to implement it.

Comment: This is the same as asking if language X supports design pattern Y: almost any pattern can be implemented in almost any language. You _can_ implement strict Inheritance in Java / smalltalk if you so choose to.

Comment: @alfasin I think you didn't understand the definition. In Strict Inheritance you cannot override methods, you can only add new methods and fields. It is not a design pattern, rather it's a mechanism. it is not implement in Java or Smalltalk (for example, you still can override the methods).

Comment: Strict inheritance may or may not happen. Enforcing it would be a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the `final` keyword in Java ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java))) and `sealed` keyword in C# ([link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sealed-class-in-C-Sharp/)). Methods marked with these keywords cannot be overridden in child classes.

I do agree that method overriding should be used with care since it can accidentally break the behavior of the parent class. So, use it only when you totally control your situation. See this [article](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2012/12/19/the-impoliteness-of-overriding-methods/) for more details.